# DataRaptor - how to do a for each comparison formula?

Tags: omnistudio, omniscript, data-raptor

I have a scenario in data raptor

I have a list of records which I want to compare with one record both part of my extract.

if the values are equal I want to set a formula to `TRUE` else `FALSE`.

This is like a for loop, where I want to loop through the list of values and compare against one value.

Do you know how to do this? I tried everything but not able to do this.

e.g.

in my extract I have an account extracted under path

```
ChildDetails:Child
```

and I have Name History extracted for that same account under path

```
ChildDetails:Child:NameHistory
```

so extract looks like

```json
    {
      "ChildDetails": {
               "Child":{
                          "FirstName":"Test",
                          "LastName":"Test",
                          "NameHistory":[
                                                {
                                                 "FirstName":"Test1",
                                                 "LastName":"Test1"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                 "FirstName":"Test2",
                                                 "LastName":"Test2"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                 "FirstName":"Test",
                                                 "LastName":"Test"
                                                }
                          ]
                }                                     
       }
    }
```

I want to compare like

> **`IF(%ChildDetails:Child:NameHistory:FirstName% == %ChildDetails:Child:FirstName%, "YES", "NO")`**

but this does not work since `%ChildDetails:Child:NameHistory:FirstName%` is taking the whole array and not each element

please let me know if you know how, any help would be appreciated. thanks a lot. in apex or in js I can do this is one second but here I tried for 3 days and still no luck and there is no documentation online to do this as well.

**desired output :**

```json
    {
      "ChildDetails": {
               "Child":{
                          "FirstName":"Test",
                          "LastName":"Test",
                          "NameHistory":[
                                                {
                                                 "FirstName":"Test1",
                                                 "LastName":"Test1",
                                                 "isFirstNameMatchWithChild":"NO"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                 "FirstName":"Test2",
                                                 "LastName":"Test2",
                                                 "isFirstNameMatchWithChild":"NO"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                 "FirstName":"Test",
                                                 "LastName":"Test",
                                                 "isFirstNameMatchWithChild":"YES"
                                                }
                          ]
                }                                     
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately such transformation is not possible in a Dataraptor Extract, but luckily there are Dataraptor Transforms!

I managed to get the required result by wrapping everything in an Integration Procedure:

[image]

I used:

1. Dataraptor Transform to extract all the matching list entries
2. Dataraptor Transform to extract all the non matching list entries
3. Merged the two lists
4. Returned the result in the required format

The Salesforce help files [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_function_reference_56716.htm&type=5) lists the function `FILTER` with some examples on how to extract a list entry with certain criteria. I ended up using:

`FILTER(LIST(FORMULA_List), 'FirstName == "' + FIRST_NAME + '"')`

which returns a list of all the list entries where the `FirstName` matches the string assigned to `FIRST_NAME`. `FORMULA_List` contained the `NameHistory` list.

I used the same formula to extract all the list entries that does not match, but changed it so that `'FirstName <> "' + FIRST_NAME + '"'`

In the Dataraptor Transform you can also add the additional JSON property `isFirstNameMatchWithChild` with its corresponding value and then return the transformed list to the Integration Procedure.

While it is not all contained in one Dataraptor as your question asked, I do feel it is better to break all the actions up in different parts which ultimately helps with debugging.

You can find the Integration Procedure [here](https://github.com/sfadriaan/Stack-Exchange-Answers/tree/main/418856) which you can import and play around with.

Good luck!